# How to use if statement in aspx file

Tags: asp.net

I've some trouble to write if statement in aspx page and additional limitation I can alter only the aspx file (not application cs files).

Original code (this asp:templateField is inside GridView):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PS" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <%#(int)Eval("PaymentStatusId") == (int)PaymentStatusEnum.Paid ? "P" : 
    (int)Eval("PaymentStatusId") == (int)PaymentStatusEnum.PendingOK ? "PINV" : "H"%>

    //all snippets below I want to put here
    
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

VARIANT 1:

If I use the URL directly it is working (but is showing in every table row):

```
<a href="https://www.company.com/et/orders/<%#((Order)Container.DataItem).Parent.OrderGuid%>/reminder" target="_blank">Send reminder</a>
```

Working code for Variant 1 ([Variant 1 output](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/12184530?key=4c4d64b83564eba4ba900fd4d23a7b73))

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PS" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#(int)Eval("PaymentStatusId") == (int)PaymentStatusEnum.Paid ? "P" : 
            (int)Eval("PaymentStatusId") == (int)PaymentStatusEnum.PendingOK ? "PINV" : "H"%>
            
                <a href="https://www.company.com/et/orders/<%#((Order)Container.DataItem).Parent.OrderGuid%>/reminder" target="_blank">Send reminder</a>
             
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

VARIANT 2:
The Variant 2 is the Variant 1 Url surrounded with if condition. My problem is that its containing errors which I'm not able to fix.

The error message is: CS1002: ; expected

```
<% if((int)Eval("PaymentStatusId") == (int)PaymentStatusEnum.PendingOK) {%> 
            
  <a href="https://www.company.com/et/orders/<%#(Order)Container.DataItem).Parent.OrderGuid/reminder%>" target="_new">Send reminder</a>
            
<%}
%>
```

VARIANT 3:

I've tried another variant:

```
<asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink1"  
              NavigateUrl="http://www.company.com/et/orders/" + <%#((Order)Container.DataItem).Parent.OrderGuid%> + "/reminder"
              Text="Send reminder"
              Target="_blank"
              Visible="<%#(int)Eval("PaymentStatusId") == (int)PaymentStatusEnum.PendingOK ? "True" : "False"%>"
              runat="server"
              />
```

Now the error message is: The server tag is not well formed. If I add `<%#((Order)Container.DataItem).Parent.OrderGuid%>` alone for example to NavidateUrl its working (but the url is not correct), but concatenation or visibilty not working.

Comment: *"but it throws an error"* - Have you tried reading the error message?

Comment: The error message: System.InvalidOperationException: Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control
and the error is happening in condition line.

Comment: And is this code placed in the context of a databound control?  The first example is part of an `<ItemTemplate>` which implies that it's within something like a list or grid control.  Where do you place the non-working example?

Comment: I intend to add my code in the code snippet comment line and this is inside <asp:GridView/>:
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PS" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                         <%#(int)Eval("PaymentStatusId") == int)PaymentStatusEnum.Paid ? "P" :   
                          (int)Eval("PaymentStatusId") == (int)PaymentStatusEnum.PendingOK ? "PINV" : "H"%>    
    
                          //code I want to add
        
      </ItemTemplate>
          
 </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: Isn't that the "working code" at the start of the question?  In what way is that "working code" not working?  Please take some time to clarify the problem in the question.

Comment: This "working code" is working as expected (according condition it is displaying "P" or "PINV". I want to add additional snippet inside <ItemTemplate> tag which has to display url then condition (int)Eval("PaymentStatusId") == (int)PaymentStatusEnum.PendingOK is true.

Comment: Then show that attempt and indicate specifically how it's failing.  Currently what you have are a variety of disconnected snippets of code and some descriptions of how you use them.  Instead, *show* how you use them.  Create a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I've modified my initial post. Hope this will clarify things.

Comment: *"but is showing in every table row"* - Isn't that what an `ItemTemplate` is for?  To render each item in the repeater/list/table/whatever?  What's the goal here?  You're trying to bind to data that's in a list of records, but don't want to use that list of records?  *"CS1002: ; expected"* - That attempt is a syntax error.  But even if you correct the syntax, you're back to the same issue as the first attempt... Trying to put something in a repeater that you don't want repeated.  It's not clear what the goal is.

Comment: Sorry David. Did you read my modified post. I want ItemTemplate content has two parts. The first part (existing now) is outputting string "P" (order is paid or "PINV" (order ise waiting payment) for every row in the table and this I want to keep as it was. I want to conditionally add the URL, then the first part value is PINV. I want to reuse `(int)Eval("PaymentStatusId") == (int)PaymentStatusEnum.PendingOK`, but I get the different syntax errors and not able to fix them.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  The `<a href` line in Variant 2 is different from the known working line in Variant 1 and contains a syntax error.  ("/reminder" should be *outisde* the server tag.)  You don't need to structurally change the working link just to wrap it in an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

you need to replace a string URL from the second condition to

`"https://www.company.com/et/orders/<%#(Order)Container.DataItem).Parent.OrderGuid%>/reminder"`

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround:

```
<a style="<%#(int)Eval("PaymentStatusId") == (int)PaymentStatusEnum.PendingOK ? "" : "display:none;"%>" href="https://interflora.codeborne.com/<%#(int)Eval("CustomerLanguageId") == 7 ? "en" : (int)Eval("CustomerLanguageId") == 8 ? "et" : (int)Eval("CustomerLanguageId") == 12 ? "ru" : "et"%>/orders/<%#((Order)Container.DataItem).Parent.OrderGuid%>/reminder" target="_blank">Send reminder</a>
```

How to get the if statement to work under these conditions will be solved in the future.